# Stored procedures call (namedparameterjdbctemplate)

Tags: java, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to call a stored procedure using jdbc. My connection is being passed through namedParameterJdbcTemplate and that's what I have to use to call it, but when I attempt to do this:

```
public void storedProcedure(long fileId, String Action) {

    String sql = "call procedureName(?)";

    try {
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, Long.valueOf(fileId) );
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while running stored procedure  {}", sql, e);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve method 'update(java.lang.String, java.lang.Long)'

Sources I've tried looking at and can't make it work:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html
- https://lalitjc.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/different-ways-of-calling-stored-procedure-using-spring/
- https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data-access-with-jdbc/spring-call-stored-procedure.html

Most of them are creating a connection from the beginning but I already have it (namedParameterJdbcTemplate), also some are using datasource which I don't need because again, I have already the connection.

How can I make the call with namedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Thank you

Comment: Try `String sql = "{call procedureName(?)}";`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't have a problem on the sql, I have a problem at calling the procedure

Comment: But your syntax is invalid to call a stored procedure through JDBC. You have to use the curly braces when using JDBC. But I think you need to use `execute()` rather than update. And a "namedParameterJdbcTemplate" doesn't use `?` for parameters, but named parameters, e.g. `:id`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok, I changed the sql statement. Regarding the execute, if I write: `namedParameterJdbcTemplate.execute(sql, action)` what do I write in action? I'm trying to simply call a stored procedure and pass a `Long` value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how it works:

```
    final String sql = "call procedureName (:variable)";

    SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource("variable", variable);

    try {
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, namedParameters);
    } catch (Exception e){
        ...     
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax looks wrong. When calling update using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, you need to call the method with either of these two method signatures.

```
update(String sql, Map<String,?> paramMap)
```

or

```
update(String sql, SqlParameterSource paramSource)
```

For further information - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html

Further example here - https://netjs.blogspot.com/2016/11/insert-update-using-namedparameterjdbctemplate-spring.html

Comment: so If my stored procedure is accepting a NUMBER, on the java update code how to I write it? The fileId is passed as Long