# Can I pass the stored procedure name as a parameter in spring jdbc? I want to ensure that there is no SQL injection as my procedure name is user input

Tags: java, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc, singlestore

I am using Spring JDBC and I want to call a stored procedure which will have only 1 String argument.
My problem is that the stored procedure name is a user input.

How to avoid SQL injection while doing this?

I am using Spring Boot and the stored procedure name is a user input and I don't have a defined entity so I am not using jpa respository.

I am using Single store DB

I tried the following but it gives me SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

```
String callStatement = String.format("ECHO %s (?)", procedureName);
Map<String, Object> res = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(callStatement, arg);
```

Comment: You can only pass values as a parameter, not object names.

Comment: Don't build the statement dynamically from user input. Map the input to the procedure. Example - for input `a` -> call procedure `x`, for `b` -> call `y`, etc. Additional bonus is that like this the client does not need to know the exact procedure name.

Comment: @Chaosfire: I cannot maintain a map separately. Any other pointers?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : Got it!! But such is my use case. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @ashu.imgud how about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295069/stored-procedures-call-namedparameterjdbctemplate

Comment: When using JDBC directly, you could use [`Statement.enquoteIdentifier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#enquoteIdentifier(java.lang.String,boolean)) before concatenating/formatting it in the query string.